# Crash in some com.google.android.gms.* module

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash, crash-reports, android-gps

I have updated my unity game with latest(November 13, 2018) Google Play Services modules. And now, I see crashes in my play console:

```
java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
Unity version     : 2018.3.0b10
Device model      : samsung SM-A520F
Device fingerprint: samsung/a5y17ltexx/a5y17lte:8.0.0/R16NW/A520FXXU7CRJA:user/release-keys
Caused by
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded (ActivityThread.java:4126)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity (ActivityThread.java:4092)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity (ActivityThread.java:4066)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity (ActivityThread.java:4040)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1708)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6944)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: 
  at i.put (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@14574051@14.5.74 (040408-219897028):101)
  at fo.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@14574051@14.5.74 (040408-219897028):44)
  at fm.onActivityPaused (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@14574051@14.5.74 (040408-219897028):53)
  at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityPaused (Application.java:249)
  at android.app.Activity.onPause (Activity.java:1734)
  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity.onPause (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.Activity.performPause (Activity.java:7408)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause (Instrumentation.java:1414)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded (ActivityThread.java:4115)
```

I guess this bug is on modules side, because I didn't saw it on the old versions.